# Layout problems with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, margin

I got some problems with layouting in CSS. Here is the code I am talking about: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJGKy/).

1. The `<div id="header">` should have the height of the `<div id="menubuttons">` which I marked red.
   I always thought that if you don't state the height of a div it will get the height of it's children.
2. The `<div class="contentLine>` is stuck to the `<div id="theme">` although I defined `margin-top: 20px;`.
3. The right column always has greater margin than the left column. I want both to have the same margin to the browser window.

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Share', cursive;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#header_logo {
    width:;
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color:;
}
#menubuttons {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 2.5em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
#menubuttons ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#menubuttons li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Share', cursive;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#theme {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left;
}
.contentLine {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 96%;
}
.contentLine .column {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: inherit;
    /* shadow for seeing div boundaries */
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px black inset;
}
.contentLine #last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me go 1 by 1

1) Your `<div id="header">` contains floated elements, you need to clear that, so use `overflow: hidden;` on parent element i.e `#header`

2) Again, you've floated `#theme` but you've set it to `width: 100%;` so you don't need float there.

3) About the last you need to set the `margins` accordingly, right now it's `1%` so you need to calculate this correctly, I would like to suggest you to use `box-sizing: border-box;` and set `33%` `width` for each element and than apply `padding-right`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJGKy/1/)

Also make sure you clear your floating elements which are nested inside `contentLine`.

---

If you are not one of those IE fans, than you can use the snippet below, which will self clear the parent element in a better way.

```
.clear:after { /* Much much better than overflow: hidden; */
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! But `header`and `menubuttons` stil don't have the same height.

Comment: @Retador *Some Issues* **Like**?

Comment: I hit Enter to fast… Edited my comment…

Comment: @Retador because you have set `margin` for `#header_logo` http://jsfiddle.net/BJGKy/2/

Comment: @Mr_Green: There is one little problem with your code: the header is coloured green now and I can't find the source. I turned all colors off but the header stays green. Do you know why?

Comment: @Retador It is in `#header{ }` as `background: #0F0`..  here `#0F0` is code for green color.

Comment: @Mr_Green Thx! I searched the document for "background-color" and "green" – that's why I couldn't find it… :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Can you help me with the box-sizing? I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/BJGKy/5/ But where should I add the padding-right?

Comment: @Retador it seems you are trying to keep some distance between the logo and menu.. then give `min-width` to `#header`. like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/BJGKy/6/). Mr.Alien, sorry for annoying you with red alerts.. :p

Answer (score 2):

Update your html

```
</ul>
<!--Menu ends here -->
    </div>
<!--menubuttons ends here -->

<!--Add following div to your code -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="theme">
```

Update your CSS

```
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

This should help.
  - will be reusable also.